# Spring Boot Using Hikari Connection Pooling not working

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am new to spring boot. I am using Spring Boot(version 2.1.4) using Hikari Connection Pooling
(version 3.2) and database is Oracle 12c. My task is when client hits the webservice, call the stored procedure and send response back to client.
Client requests are not frequent means in 2/3 days, request comes to server.

My Problem is,

My application is running continuously, but when it tries to connect database after 2/3 days, it is not able to connect. So i have to restart the application, then again client will call the webservice and get the response from server.
So, is there any way by which connection to database will be present after 2/3 days?

below is my application.properties file,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx  
spring.datasource.username=xxxx   
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Also, we need to see the code that you are using to call the stored procedure. Hikari being able to deal with invalid connections doesn't mean it will automatically recover from leaks. Is it a JDBC or JPA/Hibernate application? Are connections ever opened manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE to spring.datasource.url.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```